# Какое условие поможет скрыть от гостей лишние кнопки под записью?

Tags: wordpress

Какое условие поможет скрыть от гостей лишние кнопки под записью в вордпресс? [image: доделать-кнопка]

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //Тут кнопки
}
```

[Документация по функции is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

Comment: Выглядит логично, но меня смущает вторая кнопка -  "доделать" -  должна показываться автору поста, а не любому залогиненному пользователю. А для первой кнопки правильная рекомендация.

Comment: надо скрыть именно вторую кнопку "доделать". почему разработчик плагина не подумал об этом